# Laravel migration, can't create foreign key

Tags: laravel

Those are the following migration files:

##### User migration

```php
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->uuid('id');
    $table->string('name');
    $table->string('email')->unique();
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

##### Log migration

```php
Schema::create('log', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->uuid('id');
    $table->boolean('statu');
    $table->timestamps();
    $table->foreign('id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
});
```

When I run the migrations it shows:

> PDOException::("SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `laravel`.`log` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")")

I also tried:

```php
Schema::create('log', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->uuid('id');
    $table->boolean('statu');
    $table->timestamps();
});

Schema::table('log', function($table) {
    $table->foreign('id')
        ->references('id')
        ->on('users')
        ->onDelete('cascade');
});
```

---

```php
Schema::create('log', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->uuid('id')->primary();
    $table->foreignUuid('foreign_id');
    $table->boolean('statu');
    $table->timestamps();
});

Schema::table('log', function($table) {
    $table->foreign('foreign_id')
        ->references('id')
        ->on('users')
        ->onDelete('cascade');
});
```

But still not working.

-- I have solved this problem

User

```
 Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->uuid('id')->primary();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

log

```
Schema::create('log', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->uuid('id')->primary();
            $table->foreignUuid('user_id');
            $table->boolean('statu');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
        Schema::table('log', function($table) {
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
    
        });
```

Comment: Check data type of columns used in foreign key, they must be exact same.

Comment: Are you sure the migration of the users table is running before the log?

Comment: yap I have add some code then it is working

Answer (score 2):

Try adding to your users table :

```
$table->uuid('id')->primary();
```

Nothing here indicate to you database that id is the primary key.

Then you should call your foreign key as "name_of_the_table"_id.
For you it should be :

```
$table->foreignUuid('foreign_id');
```

And finally you can add :

```
$table->foreignUuid('user_id')->constrained();
```

The complete code is something like that :

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->uuid('id')->primary();
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->timestamps();
    });

 Schema::create('log', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->uuid('id');
        $table->boolean('statu');
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->foreignUuid('user_id')->constrained();
    });
```

Comment: Little typo: it's `constrained()`

Comment: You right sorry i didn't read my post before add it ^^

Comment: Thanks dude  , I have solved this issue

Comment: if this solution is the good one can you check it for those who can need it in the future please? Explications can help someone

Answer (score -1):

Please use $table->id(); instead of  $table->uuid('id');

Comment: Why? How would OP use UUIDs then?